# Firefox draining my PC all of a sudden

Tags: firefox, power-management, battery, overheating, fan

I have heat and loud fan problems since installing Ubuntu (16.04) but I used to manage those somehow, I have a CPU indicator near the WiFi signal, and it pretty much tells when the CPU is experiencing some workload..

I am used to Firefox so I use it daily, however all of a sudden now, everytime I open it the CPU indicator goes all the way up and fan goes crazy, so does the temperature...

What may cause this?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What are you browsing? One of your tab may have a wild Javascript, you can have a look by putting `about:performance` in the address bar of a new tab.

Comment: it's not that, even the home page of firefox (one tab) goes up to 800% CPU when monitoring it with the 'top' command

Comment: Which does not say anything as the home page can be any page, so any code. It can be an extension/plug-in also... Did you try running Firefox without any of them enabled? With a new blank profile? Did you try another Firefox version? You did not say which one you have.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should update Firefox to the newest version 59.0.2?
What about the top command - which process drains your CPU?

Comment: These are really good suggestions, but they are comments more than they are answers. Generally if you're only asking for more information (like what version of Firefox they currently have installed or for the output of a command), that's best left as a comment.